# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'

Tags: python, django

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """客户信息表"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    qq_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    source_choice = ((0, '转介绍'),
                     (1, 'QQ群'),
                     (2, '官网'),
                     (3, '百度推广'),
                     (4, '51CTO'),
                     (5, '知乎'),
                     (6, '市场推广'),
                     )
    source = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=source_choice)
    referral_from = models.CharField(verbose_name="转介绍人QQ", max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    consult_course = models.ForeignKey("Course", verbose_name="资讯课程")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="咨询详情")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True, null=True)
    consultant = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="UserProfile")
    memo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.qq


class UserProfile(models.Model):
"""用户账户表"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField("Role", bank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when i running this code（python manage.py makemigration crms） in    terminal，
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\python\CRM项目实战\CRM\crm\crms\models.py", line 26, in Customer
    consultant = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="UserProfile")
    TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'"""

Comment: anybody can answer my question ?thanks so much!

Comment: `consultant = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="UserProfile")`: You forgot to specify foreign key to what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify to which table the Foreign Key refers to,

```
consultant = models.ForeignKey(Table_name, verbose_name="UserProfile")
```

Comment: sure，actually　ｍｙ　ｅｎｇｌｉｓｈ　ｉｓ　ｐｏｏｒ！ｂｕｔ　ｉ　ｔａｋｅ　ｉｔ．

Answer (score 0):

```
consultant = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name="UserProfile")
```

You forget to define FK target table.